# vscode python linux: changes in debug console doesn't appear in 'variables->locals' debug pane

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

when I run this code:

```
a=1
print(a)
```

I put a breakpoint in the second line and in debug console I menually change `a` such that `a=5`.
the 'variables->locals' debug pane doesn't show change to `a` but when running the next line it indeed prints out `5`.
how to fix it?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new  feature in vscode, only fixed in June 19 release... now it works!